# Using Moq to assign property value when method is called

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to use Moq to assign a property when a method is called.

Something along the lines of:

```
Mock<ITimer> mock = new Mock<ITimer>();
mock.Setup(x=>x.Start()).AssignProperty(y=>y.Enabled = true);
```

Is it possible to use Moq to set an expected property value when a method is called

Comment: It certainly should be. I know Rhino will do this, so if Moq doesn't it would be surprising. I'm confident this is just a config method mixup or some other usage issue. But, I don't know Moq so I'll let someone more knowledgeable actually answer the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I assume you are trying to essentially perform a new Setup() on your Mock when the method is called? If so, you should be able to do it with a callback, like this:

```
Mock<ITimer> mock = new Mock<ITimer>();
mock.Setup(x=>x.Start()).Callback(() => mock.SetupGet(y => y.Enabled).Returns(true));
```

It's ugly, but it should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks that did it although I went with mock.Setup(x => x.Start()).Callback(() => mock.Setup(x => x.Enabled).Returns(true));